# TypeORM - generate migrations from existings entites

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Got a nest.js/typeorm/postgres application that I have been developing for the last year. Been creating/adding/removing tables/columns but never used migrations.

Now comes time to deploy and whenever I run `typeorm migration:generate`, a migration file is created for the last colums that I added/removed from only 1 or 2 tables.

Is it possible to generate a migration for all existing entities that are already part of my db schema?

Basically, the `up` would create each table with FKs, indexes, constraints, etc and the `down` would drop all of that.

Note: I noticed [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3188) post. Is this the correct approach for my issue?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. dropping and recreating my database in postgres
2. ran `npm run typeorm:reset`
3. then `npm run typeorm:migrate`
4. then `typeorm:run`

scripts for reference

**package.json**

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
    "typeorm:sync": "npm run typeorm schema:sync",
    "typeorm:drop": "npm run typeorm schema:drop",
    "typeorm:reset": "npm run typeorm:drop && npm run typeorm:sync",
    "typeorm:migrate": "env NODE_ENV=development npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n",
    "typeorm:create": "env NODE_ENV=development npm run typeorm migration:create -- -n",
    "typeorm:run": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register $(yarn bin typeorm) migration:run"
```

**ormconfig.js**

```
const config = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.RDS_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.RDS_PORT),
  username: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
  synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false,
  entities: [`${__dirname}/src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}`],
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/src/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}`],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
}

module.exports = config
```

Note:

- in my typeORM scripts, I use `tsconfig-paths/register` because I have path aliases in my tsconfig.json file that I use in my `*.entity.ts` files.

Comment: can you share what is in `tsconfig-paths/register`?